# How to use Foxit Phantom PDF invisibly

Tags: vba, ms-access, pdf, foxit

Is there a way to create a PDF file in VBA code using Foxit Phantom PDF without the FoxIt app being visible to the user?

(Running it using VBA in an MS Access database)

Answer (score 1):

This document may be of assistance.
http://cdn01.foxitsoftware.com/pub/foxit/manual/phantom/en_us/API%20Reference%20for%20Application%20Communication.pdf